# Matching dates to report review schedules

Tags: csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, string-matching

I have a table that lists events, their report dates, and the dates when the events are reviewed, e.g.

```
ID | REPORT_DATE | RFD
1  | 2021-02-01  | 1st,15th
2  | 2021-02-16  | Tuesday
3  | 2021-02-14  | 4th,1st,8th,15th,23rd
4  | 2021-02-01  | 1st
5  | 2021-02-28  | 1st, Last
```

I've developed a query that pulls rows 2 and 4 (see query below) but fails to find matching values within comma-separated values.

```
select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE, RFD
from DB
where (lower(RFD) = lower(trim(to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'Day'))) or RFD like trim(to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmddth')) and RFD is not NULL)
```

I haven't found any online discussion that can hint at how to solve this issue. I was considering transforming the comma-separated values into arrays and searching within that, but I was wondering if there was a simpler solution?

*Clarification:
I'm trying to pull all the the records where the report date (and it's characteristics match); so it should pull events where the date and RFD contain a matching day-of-week, are on the 1st of a month or the last of a month (ids: 1, 2, 4, 5).

Comment: Fixed the noted issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data can't be normalised then converting the CSV values to multiple rows on the fly is an option. You could also use regular expression patterns, e.g:

```
select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE, RFD
from DB
where regexp_like(lower(RFD), '(^| |,)' || to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmday') || '(,| |$)')
or regexp_like(lower(RFD), '(^| |,)' || to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmddth') || '(,| |$)')
or (regexp_like(lower(RFD), '(^| |,)last(,| |$)') and REPORT_DATE = last_day(REPORT_DATE));

 EVENT_ID | REPORT_DATE | RFD      
 -------: | :---------- | :--------
        1 | 2021-02-01  | 1st,15th 
        2 | 2021-02-16  | Tuesday  
        4 | 2021-02-01  | 1st      
        5 | 2021-02-28  | 1st, Last
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e5080f4c0bd80f1f437cc91b5211832f)

Performance may be an issue though, if you have a lot of data to process.

If you want to split the CSV strings into rows there are various approaches, including with regular expressions again:

```
select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE, regexp_substr(RFD, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) as RFD
from DB
connect by EVENT_ID = prior EVENT_ID
and level <= regexp_count(RFD, ',') + 1
and prior dbms_random.value is not null
```

or with a recursive CTE and simpler/faster string functions:

```
with rcte (EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE, VALUE, RFD) AS (
  select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE,
    lower(trim(case when instr(RFD, ',') > 0 then substr(RFD, 1, instr(RFD, ',') - 1) else RFD end)),
    lower(trim(case when instr(RFD, ',') > 0 then substr(RFD, instr(RFD, ',') + 1) end))
  from DB
  where RFD is not null
  union all
  select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE,
    trim(case when instr(RFD, ',') > 0 then substr(RFD, 1, instr(RFD, ',') - 1) else RFD end),
    trim(case when instr(RFD, ',') > 0 then substr(RFD, instr(RFD, ',') + 1) end)
  from rcte
  where RFD is not null
)
...
```

and you can then check the individual rows:

```
...
select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE, VALUE
from rcte
where VALUE = to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmday')
or VALUE = to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmddth')
or (VALUE = 'last' and REPORT_DATE = last_day(REPORT_DATE))
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=16e8b6f5ee4f5671dd950590707fa890)

You might get multiple hits with this approach - if your second ID had RFD `Tuesday, 16th` for instance - which you may want, or may need to suppress.

As always there are trade-offs, between speed and memory usage, so exploring multiple solutions is probably a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Haven't tested this out yet, but I wanted to add there is a lot of data to this. Would transforming these data to rows then be recommended?

Comment: @JamesR. - it depends on how you split them, and how much data there is. It might be worth testing both ways, and with different split methods.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Alex Poole who was able to answer my question with their query, which I believe they had recently updated, but below is the one that had worked for my situation. The dataset used contained 3.5 million records x 12 fields and completed it in less than 0.5 seconds. Below is a portion of the query which uses Alex's code.

```
select EVENT_ID, REPORT_DATE, RFD
from DB
where (regexp_like(lower(RFD), '(^| |,)' || to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmday') || '(,| |$)') 
    or regexp_like(lower(RFD), '(^| |,)' || to_char(REPORT_DATE, 'fmddth') || '(,| |$)')
    or (regexp(lower(RFD), '(^| |,)last(,| |$)' and REPORT_DATE = last_day(REPORT_DATE)) 
    or RFD is NULL)
)
```